# Passing value from bind function of select form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use a select/option form that has been 'bind'in jsniceit.js to improve form format. It looks nice rather than standard form. But I can not use OnClick function on the form to pass data for ajax call. My form is to show city in a dropdown select form after selecting a state.

My question is, how to pass value of select/option form from this (just showing parts of the jsniceit.js) where bind is located.

```
$(ctrl).find('option').each(function(idx, item) {
    nCtrl.find('ul').append('<li option="' + $(item).attr('value') +
        '">' + $(item).text() + '</li>');
});

nCtrl.find('li').each(function(num, elem) {
    $(elem).bind('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    $(elem).bind('mouseout', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

    $(elem).bind('click', function() {
        nCtrl.find(cite).text($(this).text());
        $(ctrl).val($(this).attr('option'));
        nCtrl.find('ul').fadeOut();

        alert('option'.value);

    });
});
```

I was trying to pass value with alert, but it returns undefined.

Comment: Did you mean `$(this).attr("option")`?  Because `'option'.value` is clearly going to be `undefined`.

Comment: you should probably use a data-attribute rather than making up your own attributes

Comment: I want to return the value of the selected 'option'. I have changed 'option' to 'select' but still return undefined.